# Count by date of top 5 values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of `defect_description` and `productionday` fields as follows:

```sql
+--------------------+---------------+
| defect_description | productionday |
+--------------------+---------------+
| BLOWN GASKET       | 2020-01-01    |
| BLOWN GASKET       | 2020-01-01    |
| BLOWN GASKET       | 2020-01-01    |
| BLOWN TIRE         | 2020-01-01    |
| BLOWN LIGHT        | 2020-01-01    |
| BLOWN LIGHT        | 2020-01-01    |
| BLOWN LIGHT        | 2020-01-01    |
| BLOWN LIGHT        | 2020-01-01    |
| BLOWN TIRE         | 2020-02-01    |
| BLOWN TIRE         | 2020-02-01    |
| BLOWN TIRE         | 2020-02-01    |
+--------------------+---------------+
```

How can I count of top 5 defects per day:

```sql
+---------------+--------------------+-------+
| productionday | defect_description | count |
+---------------+--------------------+-------+
| 2020-01-01    | BLOWN LIGHT        |     4 |
| 2020-01-01    | BLOWN GASKET       |     3 |
| 2020-01-01    | BLOWN TIRE         |     1 |
| 2020-02-01    | BLOWN TIRE         |     3 |
+---------------+--------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Please mention your product  and version.

Answer (score 0):

This would work in SQL Server.

```
;WITH daysCTE as
(
    SELECT DISTINCT productionday
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT daysCTE.productionday, t.*
FROM daysCTE 
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 5
       defect_description, 
       Count(*) NumberOfDefects
    FROM   YourTable
    WHERE  productionday= daysCTE.productionday
    GROUP BY defect_description
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
) t
```

Comment: Works perfect!! Thanks

Comment: @JeremyReynolds if Gabriel's answer is works for you, please accept this.

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work in Postgres SQL

```
select * from(
select *,rank() over (partition by productionday order by c desc ) as rank
from (
select defect_description, productionday, count(*) as c
        from tab
        group by productionday,defect_description
) A
) B
where rank <=5
```

[Check the Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6d24075fe438d5e8de5a2a58fd1e4497)

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select defect_description, productionday, count(*) as c,
             row_number() over (partition by productionday order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from tab
      group by productionday, defect_description
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5
```